# How can i type hindi matras only in Latex?

Tags: unicode, languages, indic

I am dealing with suffix of the hindi words. so i want something like this 
`ाऊंगी` in hindi to be printed.

For uni character of hindi language is [here](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0900.pdf).

I have tried this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{devanagari}
\begin{document}
 {\dn Auu.mgii}
\end{document}
```

But it gives me output as:
`आऊंगी`

Actually i need from the first character U+0906+093E the part with U+093E, in hindi its `ा` from `आ`

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of above code, if you will run the following code, directly in your .tex file then you will get the correct output

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{devanagari}  
\begin{document}  
{\dn AU{\qva}gF}  
\end{document}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.